# 'chromedriver.exe' executable needs to be in PATH error

Tags: python, node.js, selenium-webdriver

I'm currently coding a Python file that can be crawled with a chrome web driver when requested by the nodejs server.

I've already used an absolute route with a Chrome web driver.
And I've tried module `'webdriver-manager'`, but it says `'No module named 'webdriver_manager''`

**File directory structure**

```
project
  L module
    L crawling
      L chromedriver.exe
      L crawling.py
  L router
    L controller
      L api
        L index.js
```

**node.js server : index.js**

```
router.get('/', async(req, res) => {
    const filePath = path.join(__dirname, '..', '..', '..', 'module', 'crawling') + '/crawling.py';

    pythonShell.PythonShell.run(filePath, null, (err, result) => {
        console.log(result)
        if (err) {
            console.log(err.message)
        } else {
            console.log('finished');
        } 
    })
```

**python code : crawling.py**

```py
...
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
...
```

I hope to be crawling with web drivers when a request is made to the server.

Comment: You need to provide the path of the Chromedriver exe inside the `webdriver.Chrome()` as arguments.

Comment: An error occurs even though both absolute and relative paths are put in parentheses.